# Не работает функция rotateX

Tags: javascript, геометрия, примитивы

Использую p5.js (https://editor.p5js.org/), не получается посмотреть что я нарисовал по другим осям.

Хоть я вызываю rotateX но почему-то она не отрабатывает.

```
function setup()  {
    createCanvas( 200, 200, WEBGL);
    angle = 0.0; // так тоже работает _angle = 0
    
    my_point_size = 20; 
    my_layer = 170;       
}
function feet() {
     R1 = 10; 
    
    // первый слой 
     angle_t1 = 0;
    
    for( i = 0; my_point_size/4>= i; i++)
    {
        point(R1*cos(angle_t1), R1*sin(angle_t1), 0);
       angle_t1 +=(TWO_PI)/(my_point_size/2);
    }
   
   R2_x = R1;
   R2_y = 0.0;
   
    for( i = 0; my_point_size/4 >= i; i++)
    {
        R2_y -= R1/2;
        point(R2_x, R2_y, 0);
    }
    
    angle_t1 -=(TWO_PI)/(my_point_size/2);
    for( i = 0; my_point_size/4 >= i; i++)
    {
        point(R1*cos(angle_t1), R2_y + R1*sin(angle_t1), 0);
       angle_t1 +=(TWO_PI)/(my_point_size/2);
    }
    
      R2_x = -R1;
      for( i = 0; my_point_size/4 >= i; i++)
    {
        R2_y += R1/2;
        point(R2_x, R2_y, 0);
    }
}

function legs() { 
    feet() ;
}

function my_rotate() {
    rotateX(angle);
    //rotateY(_angle);
    //rotateZ(_angle);
    
    angle += 0.1;
}
    
function draw() {
    background(220,220,220, 5);
    
    // rectMode(CENTER); //центритует рисунок
    stroke(0, 0, 156, 200);  // даëм точке цвет
    strokeWeight(3);          // ширина точки
    
    legs() ; // рисуем
    my_rotate(); // крутим
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Первично в библиотеке "крутят" а потом "отрисовывают"

```
... 
my_rotate(); // крутим
legs() ; // рисуем
...
```

https://discourse.processing.org/t/why-rotatex-function-not-working/39097

Comment: а draw разве не вызывается в цикле и вращение все равно должно было быть заметным?

Comment: @Grundy я сам поразился что " от перемены мест слагаемых сумма меняется ".  Также заметил что переменные надо обязательно занулять по старту так как он постоянно перересовывает.

Comment: Тут не совсем сумма, скорее произведение.